# Creating NGrams in R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am trying to write ngram code in R. Below code works fine when I use stemDocument (corpus<- tm_map(corp_inputFile, stemDocument)). But gives an error when I don't use stemDocument.

```
   BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3))
   tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
   forExport <- as.matrix(inspect(tdm))
   write.csv(forExport, 'C:/myfile.csv')
```

Error Message:

```
   Error in .jcall("RWekaInterfaces", "[S", "tokenize", .jcast(tokenizer,  : 
       java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please guide

Comment: The issue is most likely in your input file, but is irreproducible here with the proper data set provided. Try to isolate it and give the data producing the error here.

Comment: Thank you Dr VComas. Raw data had a a lot of blank rows. After removing those rows, it worked.